# Getting error when reporting a YouTube video

Tags: python, flask, youtube, youtube-data-api, google-api-python-client

I am trying to report a YouTube video abuse from my Python Flask web application using the Google API client library. However, I am encountering an error when executing the `youtube.videos().reportAbuse()` method. The error message reads as follows:

> `googleapiclient.errors.HttpError: <HttpError 400 when requesting https://youtube.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos/reportAbuse? returned "The request contained an unexpected value for the <code>reason_id</code> field, or a combination of the <code>reason_id</code> and <code>secondary_reason_id</code> fields.". Details: "[{'message': 'The request contained an unexpected value for the <code>reason_id</code> field, or a combination of the <code>reason_id</code> and <code>secondary_reason_id</code> fields.', 'domain': 'youtube.video', 'reason': 'invalidAbuseReason', 'location': 'body.reason_id', 'locationType': 'other'}]">`

I have checked my code and confirmed that all the required parameters are being provided. How can I fix this error? Here is the relevant code block:

```py
video_id = 'VIDEOID'

report = {
  'reasonId': 'SPAM',
  'videoId': video_id,
  'language': 'en'
}

youtube.videos().reportAbuse(body=report).execute()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking over the API docs for the [reportAbuse API call](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/reportAbuse):

> Specifies the reason that the video that is being reported for
> containing abusive content. Set the value to the appropriate
> videoAbuseReportReason resource's unique ID

Which requires the unique ID of the reason. This is obtained from a [list on videoAbuseReportReasons](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videoAbuseReportReasons#id). Unfortunately I did a quick test API call and wasn't able to find the SPAM reason you mentioned to obtain the API for it. You'll have to pick one of the returned reasons from the API, including a possible secondary reason if it appears in the child nodes.

Answer (score 1):

The response appears to indicate that "SPAM" is not a valid VideoAbuseReportReason. You can use something like

```
request = youtube.videoAbuseReportReasons().list(part="snippet").execute()
```

to retrieve a list of allowed values.

Answer (score 0):

In the [linked documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos) it says:

> **Step 2: Flag the video for abusive content**
>
> [...] the ID for Spam or misleading content is ***S***.[...]

So, in your code, you should try changing the request as follows:

```
video_id = 'VIDEOID'

report = {
    'reasonId': 'S',
    'videoId': video_id,
    'language': 'en'
}

youtube.videos().reportAbuse(body=report).execute()
```

Please [check closely the documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/guides/implementation/videos#videos-report-abuse), because as I read it - see ***Step 1: Retrieve IDs that explain why the video is being reported*** - , I understand you need to set a `secondaryReason` value for the repórt.

Comment: The request cannot be made anymore from what another person has told me, so your code will no longer work.